# changing Python code in the debugger

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x

Is there any debugger that allows Python code to be changed while debugging?

In other words: run-time exception occurs, debugger stops, I change the code any way I like, and tell the program to continue.

**I am aware** of the problems with this approach, such that references to functions would still point to the old definitions if I redefine the function on the fly, and so on. I am ok with that, since I just want to be able to make small fixes in very simple circumstances.

On the other hand, I'm also interested in whether it's theoretically possible to allow changes to Python code without running into these problems: i.e., somehow update all the references to the objects that changed, etc. I'm nearly sure the answer to the second question is no, but if I'm wrong, I'd like to know.

EDIT: If my goal (changing the code interactively when an exception occurred, and then continuing execution), is achievable without a debugger - that would be good as well. I don't need to use the debugger.

Comment: why need a debugger? I use python for a while now and I never felt the need for one..

Comment: @Gabi: because a debugger lets you browse variables to see their values, execute functions on the fly, and check to see whether code is being run, rather than relying on print statements. If you're troubleshooting complicated logic or large amounts of data, debuggers become invaluable.

Comment: @Jordan: in the last 30 years, I've used a debugger once to find a stack trace in a C core file.  All the things you suggest can be done other ways.  A debugger isn't really "invaluable".  It's just a preference.

Comment: @Gabi: see my edit to the question. I don't need to use the debugger.

Comment: @max: It's generally a pretty bad idea.  With or without the debugger, what you're talking about is generally senseless.  Small fixes in simple circumstances is just "edit and rerun".  What's stopping you from editing and rerunning?

Comment: @S.Lott he's used Visual Studio Edit and Continue and can't contemplate life without

Comment: I suppose I should stop commenting, since I can't understand the use case at all.

Comment: @S Lott Use case: I made an error in a function that was caught by assert. It took a few minutes to get the execution to that point. I know the function wasn't passed as a parameter anywhere etc. I can fix the code and continue execution not having to wait another few minutes. And your comments are appreciated.

Comment: @S.Lott: Saying that a debugger isn't invaluable is like saying that a for loop isn't invaluable because you can do it with GOTO's. :) I saw a blog post recently which mentioned that several famous programmers never used debuggers. I think they are all crazy, and would be converts if they just tried for a week. :-)

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: "saying...debugger isn't invaluable is like saying that a for loop isn't invaluable".  Bad analogy.  I'm not "working around" the absence of the debugger with something that's a completely bad idea.  I can't find a use case for it at all.  I'm well aware of how much people depend on it.  I've had numerous co-workers and students who are heavy and successful users of a debugger.  For a few, the debugger was a liability -- their code was filled with random `a=a+1` things because they discovered that `a` had the wrong value.  And they never figured out *why*.

Comment: @max: "It took a few minutes to get the execution to that point".  That indicates that your test design is flawed.  Not that you need a debugger.  You need better unit test cases so you don't have to wait minutes.

Comment: @S.Lott: Debuggers won't help bad programmers, this is true. But I have also worked without a debugger, and I'm convinced you are wrong when you are saying you aren't working around the absence of the debugger. Sorry. Just the way you can, after you have discovered that a value is wrong (which you could do with a print instead), go up in the call stack to see where the incorrect value comes from, is invaluable and speeds up debugging a lot. Really. I'm not trying to convince you to use a debugger, but claiming it's not an invaluable tool is just wrong. Same thing with a good editor.

Comment: @S.Lott, et al: if you say you don't need a debugger, I believe you, because I agree; my point is that often a debugger is a better tool than print statements/dumps/whatever if you're working on complicated tasks, multi-threaded apps, or simply want to see what results you get from executing a function within a context without copy/paste ad infinitum. Like any tool, a debugger depends on the user's ability to use it.

Comment: All I can say is that your lives are too complex for me.  Perhaps it's because I've designed my software to be so simple that a debugger doesn't help.  Or, perhaps, I'm just crippled and don't know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can change the contents of regular classes the way you want at any time, there's no need to update references to objects: you just update class's `__dict__` with new methods and other attributes.

The problem is with references to functions: you can't update a function without changing its identity. You can use proxy functions that always look up real functions by name, and you change real functions at any moment. Else, you plan your code so that it doesn't store function references for long; once a function is updated, it will soon be looked up by name, but old references passed somewhere will continue to execute for a bit longer.

Such patching would make sense on a long-running system when you want to upgrade it without serious downtime: you pause it for a moment to upgrade several classes and functions consistently and un-pause. AFAIK Erlang does its on-the-fly updates in a similar way.

Comment: +1 I didn't know functions cannot be changed without changing the identity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, pdb can do this. Although you have to do the editing in another editor, and the changes will be ignored until you restart.

But since all you want to do is small changes, this is not a problem. But you can't change the running code (except with reload, see below), as changing the code would mean the code and the state is out of sync.

What you can do with a debugger is test the change you want to do. You can paste in the code as you want to change it, and thus test that it is correct without rerunning the whole program. But in that case you don't edit the file.

(In some specific cases you might be able to get away with not restarting by careful use of "reload()", but that's probably not worth the effort.)

Answer (score 1):

You can update the code in a running python process with xreload:

http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/xreload/xreload.py

There are many limitations, they are listed at the top of the file.  I'm not sure if this handles the case you want though - do you want to actually prevent the exception from propagating?  That requires more than updating the running program.

Comment: Thank you - it's an interesting tool, but I realize now it's probably not worth doing this due to the complexities involved.

Answer (score -2):

name = (input("Enter Name: "))

if name == "e":
    print ("This word has a letter e")

else :
    print("This word has no letter e")

Comment: you did  not answer anything related to the question. Frankly I'm confused why this is relevant to finding a debugger.

Answer (score -3):

> whether it's theoretically possible to allow changes to Python code

Yes.  It's possible to update a code object "on the fly".  Nothing in the Python VM seems to prevent this.  There's not an ongoing verification of the checksums or anything.

> somehow update all the references to the objects that changed,

This doesn't even make sense.  Once the class-level method definition is changed, "updating" all the references isn't even necessary or sensible.  The code is changed in the one and only place it exists.

This is why debuggers are bad.  They seem to lead to murky, unclear thinking.  Thinking too much about the debugger means thinking too little about the real problem at hand.

TDD is a far, far better investment.  Small, manageable unit tests run quickly and provide enduring evidence that things  work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development